# Show Subscript or SuperScript text same as from Database in rdlc

Tags: c#, rdlc

I have data with subscript i.e "C₈H₁₇NO₂". In database subscript values 8, 17 and 2 are character symbols in word which is pasted. But when same value is pasted in text box of rdlc it is right but when same value is added to table in rdlc through dataset it is subscript values are changed to different symbols. Below are two images, I have highlighted the data with subscript:
[Image where subscript is correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2pB7.png)
[Image where subscript values are changed to diff symbols](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uO0x.png)

First is in grid and second pic is in rdlc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, finally I got the solution for above question. C₈H₁₇NO₂ is in Calibri font.So I just changed font face of text box in my rdlc from  Arial to Calibri and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

The `RDLC` can accept different formatting styles, the one that you're looking for in this case is the "Interpret html tags as styles". This will render elements such as `<sub></sub>` a subscript in your textbox. Navigate to the Text Properties > General Tab > and then select "Interpret html tags as styles".

```
C<sup>8</sup>H<sup>17</sup>NO<sup>2</sup>
```

Renders like this:

C₈H₁₇NO₂

Comment: David bro, I have seen this solution before. But this is not what i need to do. my data C₈H₁₇NO₂ comes from database in dataset and I have given that dataset as a source of table. Now how to get that??

Comment: This cannot be done if the data from the DB is already coming back with subscript `ASCII` characters, as that functionality is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

The RDLC option of "Interpret HTML tags as styles" has some limitations. Not all HTML tags will be interpreted.
This worked for me: http://sqljason.com/2010/12/subscripts-and-superscripts-in-ssrs.html
while keeping font style as Arial.